# update value in config.php with another php script

Tags: php

I include a config.php file in all of my pages.
I also have a cron job which updates a total count of a table, into another table each hour.
I want to also write that value into the config and save if possible.

my config is in the structure:

```
return array(
    'stats' => array(
        'total_count' => 130000,
        'another_stat' => 100000,
    ),
    'other_config_value' => 'value',
)
```

and I include it in my pages, at the top like:

```
$config = include('../php/config.php');
$total_count = $config['stats']['total_count']
```

just so I don't have to query the database on each page, every time it loads as I want to show that total on all pages.

Comment: Would it not be better to save this total of yours in a cache instead, as your solution means that this number will be "out of date" for 59 minutes out of every hour. Hardly seems worth showing something that is that inaccurate on every page

Comment: `'total_count' => 130000` where does 130000 come from?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio at the moment its a static, rough value. I want to update it to be the result of a SELECT COUNT(*) query

Comment: that's exactly the solution: execute your query inside config.php, change your statement regarding total_count to something like `'total_count' => $queryResult`, then return your array

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your config in JSON format and use functions json_decode() to read it. If yout want update it you can use json_decode() to make an array from JSON string, update this value in array and use json_encode() to make JSON string from array. After that you can save it to file with file_put_contents().

```
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'));
$config['value'] = $newValue;
file_put_contents('config.json', json_encode($config));
```